TanStack Query v5: Issues with useQuery Syntax and Fetching Data in React typescript
How can i resolve these error in Typescript
Errors are :
on queryFn (
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3, '(options: DefinedInitialDataOptions<AxiosResponse<any, any>, Error, AxiosResponse  <any, any>, (string | null)[]>, queryClient?:...)
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any, any>
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any, any>
const ProjectList: React.FC<ProjectListProps> = ({ selectedDomain }) => {
  const {
    data: projects = [],
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['projects', selectedDomain],
    queryFn: () => {
      if (selectedDomain) {
        return getProjectsByDomain(selectedDomain);
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
      }
    },
    enabled: !!selectedDomain,
    onError: (err: any) => {
      console.error('Error loading projects:', err);
    },
  });

  const message =
    projects.length === 0
      ? `We do not have projects in ${selectedDomain}. We will have more projects soon.`
      : '';

  return (
    <div className="project-list-container">
      {message && <div className="no-projects-message">{message}</div>}
      {projects.length > 0 ? (
        projects.map((project: Project) => (
          // logic
        ))
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};


I tried everything but it's not able to resolve these.
